# How i can use images in models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-settings

Django can't find the path to the image
settings.py

```
import os, sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'homepage.apps.HomepageConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

views.py

```
def champs(request, champ_id):
    try:
        champ = Champion.objects.get( id = champ_id )
    except:
        raise Http404("Page is not found :|")

    return render(request, 'homepage/champs.html', {'champ': champ})
```

models.py

```
class Champion(models.Model):
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme, verbose_name = "Тема", on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = 0)
    champion_name = models.CharField("Имя чемпиона", max_length = 25, unique = True)
    champion_name2 = models.CharField("Прозвище чемпиона", max_length = 40, default = 0)
    champion_lor = models.TextField("История чемпиона")
    champion_role = models.CharField("Роль чемпиона", max_length = 30, default = 0)
    champion_image = models.ImageField("Фото чемпиона", upload_to = 'homepage', null = True, blank = True)
    champion_patch_date = models.CharField("Патч и дата выхода чемпиона", max_length = 100, default = 0)
    champion_money = models.CharField("Стоимость чемпиона", max_length = 50, default = 0)
    champion_line = models.CharField("Линия чемпиона", max_length = 30, default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.champion_name
```

champ.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Champions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/champ.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>{{champ.champion_name}}</h1>
        <h3>{{champ.champion_name2}}</h3>
        <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{champ.champion_image.url}}">
        <hr class = "hr_2">
        <p class = role_1>Класс:  <em class = "role">{{champ.champion_role}}</em></p>
        <p class = "money_1">Стоимость: <em class = "money">{{champ.champion_money}}</em></p>
        <p class = "line_1">Линия: <em class = "line">{{champ.champion_line}}</em></p>
        <p class = "patch_1">Дата выхода:<em class = "patch">{{champ.champion_patch_date}}</em></p>
        <p class = "lor"><em>{{champ.champion_lor}}</em></p>
        <hr class = "hr_1">
        <p class = "p_1">@Все права защищены</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

app_name = 'homepage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('patch', views.patch, name = 'patch'),
    path('patch/patch<int:patch_id>', views.patches, name = 'patches'),
    path('champ', views.champ, name = 'champ'),
    path('champ/champ<int:champ_id>', views.champs, name = 'champs'),
    path('ivent', views.ivents, name = "ivents"),
    path('ivent/ivent<int:ivent_id>', views.ivent, name = 'ivent'),
    path('item', views.items, name = 'items'),
    path('item/item<int:item_id>', views.item, name = 'item'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I run the site, the console displays "Not found /media/homepage/Azir.jpg".
I don't understand why django can't find an image along this path.
The last thing I did was add

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in urls.py, but nothing has changed.
I think it might be a bug with settings.py. Maybe I wrote MEDIA_ROOT incorrectly or something else and therefore django cannot find the path to the image

Comment: never post your secret key

Answer (score 0):

but according to model you have one image for each object then you can take only one image if you want to get two images then why don't you specify two image field

```
class Champion(models.Model):
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme, verbose_name = "Тема", on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = 0)
    champion_name = models.CharField("Имя чемпиона", max_length = 25, unique = True)
    champion_name2 = models.CharField("Прозвище чемпиона", max_length = 40, default = 0)
    champion_lor = models.TextField("История чемпиона")
    champion_role = models.CharField("Роль чемпиона", max_length = 30, default = 0)
    champion_image = models.ImageField("Фото чемпиона", upload_to = 'homepage', null = True, blank = True)
    champion_patch_date = models.CharField("Патч и дата выхода чемпиона", max_length = 100, default = 0)
    champion_money = models.CharField("Стоимость чемпиона", max_length = 50, default = 0)
    champion_line = models.CharField("Линия чемпиона", max_length = 30, default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.champion_name
```

Comment: I think it might work, but I have a lot of champions that I display to the site using their id. And if I point path directly, there will be 1 image for each champion. And should be different for everyone

Comment: How can I make a direct path for each object so that each champion has a different image?